# Explode only on last comment, skip # inside variable

Tags: php, regex

A sample values like this:

```
fdsfsf345#3gt#$%3^#$T$#tr43r43
test spaces
"test spaces"

"fdsfsf345#3gt#$%3^#$T$#tr43r43" #comment
"test spaces" #comment
```

A script:

```
$re = '/(.*)(?:\"|\'|)(?: )#?(.*)|(.*)/mi';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

A problem is that a line without '# comment' prints

A result should be on first array:

```
fdsfsf345#3gt#$%3^#$T$#tr43r43
test spaces
"test spaces"

"fdsfsf345#3gt#$%3^#$T$#tr43r43"
"test spaces"
```

https://regex101.com/r/IpcEPU/1

Comment: `#` after a space is optional for the 2nd named capturing group, it should be mandatory

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` or lookarounds come to my mind but what is the expected output? As a side note, the dot-star-soup seems very inefficient.

Comment: I want if '#comment' in line, it will remove them from line. A problem is '#' in value but I will not want to explode them.

Comment: @MarinSagovac: Like this: https://regex101.com/r/UqIdoM/2 ? Otherwise, please give more realistic input examples.

Comment: Your examples only have `#comment` at the end of the line. Do you mean not match it when it is [at the end of the line](https://regex101.com/r/lKZ6aV/1)? Or you could match it and [replace it](https://regex101.com/r/lKZ6aV/3).

Comment: That is what I've looking for. Regex: `^.+?(?= #(.*)$|$)`. It will not include any `# comment` or  `# comment2`.

Comment: If you just want to remove `#comment` from lines why not use `str_replace` or `preg_replace`? Also the modifiers you're using, `mi`, aren't doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sample input, you only need to remove substrings from space-hash to the end of the line.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/8pje0))

```
$array = [
    'bar',
    'fdsfsf345#3gt#$%3^#$T$#tr43r43',
    'test spaces',
    '"test spaces"',
    '"fdsfsf345#3gt#$%3^#$T$#tr43r43" #comment',
    'test spaces" #comment',
    'bar',
    '""',
    '""""',
    'foo1 #comment2',
    '"with space value" #comment',
    'with quote value\'',
    'somestringstart',
    'with spaces" # a comment',
    'bar'
];

$result=preg_replace('~ #.*~','',$array);
var_export($result);
```

---

If you may have space-hash substrings inside of your quoted text, then `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` will help by disqualifying these values.

Pattern: `'~(["']).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)| #.*~'` Replace: `''` (empty string)

This will ensure that single or double quote-wrapped space-hash substrings are not matched/removed.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution with regex:

```
/(?=(^(.*)[ ])(?=#[ a-z0-9]+))|(?=(^(.*))+)/i
```

It will parse only values and skip with any type comments.

https://regex101.com/r/dFVhjr/1

If have any improved idea it will be welcome.